# Oracle: tracing SQL statements

Tags: asp.net, oracle, debugging, trace

I'm maintaining an home-brew web-based help-desk solution and we are experiencing an erroneous change in a db field under some circumstances. The code involved is quite frankly a mess, mixing different approaches to database access (the worst and most dangerous one being building sql strings through concatenation). A full-text search of the problematic field in the entire solution didn't help (the field only appeared in selects and in a single legitimate insert) so I can't even find the offending code.

Do you know a fast way to **enable sql tracing** either in Asp.Net or in Oracle (8) itself? (Is it possible to intercept sql commands through the OracleConnection object or something like that? That would make it possible to get a stack trace and find out the buggy code).

I've done some googling and I've found this one: `ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true SCOPE=MEMORY;` but I'd like to know which is the better way to solve the problem (and maybe build up a simple sql logging mechanism without rewriting the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling tracing is the way to go, but if you're having trouble getting that working, try to see if you can find reference to the offending column in the sql_text column of SYS.v$sql.  Assuming that the statement has run recently (and that the statement that did the deed isn't so long that the column you're looking for has been truncated - Oracle 8 didn't store the full text), you should be able to locate it there.  The only other case where the SQL wouldn't show up there is if the change were occuring via a trigger or stored proc, in which case you should be able to locate the column in the TEXT column of the ALL_SOURCES table.

Comment: the v$sql table provided enough info to solve the problem,
thank you

Answer (score 4):

To trace a specific session in Oracle 8 use the [PROCEDURE DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/DBMS_System.php)

[TKPROF And Oracle Trace (8i)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/TKPROFAndOracleTrace.php)

Might be of interest:

- [Tracing SQL in Oracle Database 10g](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/04-sep/o54talking.html)
- [SQL Trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace)
- [Using SQL Trace and TKPROF](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm#1018)
- [Using Application Tracing Tools](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/support/oracle/doc/10.2/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm)

Comment: Thank you, I've already come across the orafaq page through google, I'll have a look at the others (the first one related to "PROCEDURE DBMS..." seems to be broken: I get a 404). Still looking for something more asp.net OracleClient related (if such a thing exists).

Comment: @Utaal: that link was broken! Sorry, Have updated to the Oracle 8i page